# Hebrew system locale in android emulator

Tags: android, locale, emulation, hebrew

While my app can display Hebrew text (even in the emulator, so the fonts are present) I am not able to set the system locale to Hebrew in order to be able to test the translations of the strings. Any idea how can I do it? Hebrew or Iwrit doesn't show up in the list of "Custom Locale" or "Settings" app in the emulator with the latest AVD, android 4.4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To test Hebrew translation (or any other non present locale) at emulator:

- open all apps
- locate "Custom Locale" app and launch it
- press "Add new" button and at the dialog popup write "he", press "add and select" button

Now when you open your app it will use your hebrew strings translation.

To find others locale codes you can use http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-codes.asp LCID string row.